# Addition of two vectors in diff dimensions

Tags: vectors

Let's suppose I have two vectors $(1, 2)$ and $(1, 2, 3)$ in $2D$ and $3D$, respectively. And I know vector addition with unequal dimensions is not defined. But if I could make the first vector as $(1, 2, 0)$, is it ok then to add these two vectors?

Comment: "*if I could make the first vector as (1,2,0)*"  Yes... the addition $(1,2,0)+(1,2,3)$ is perfectly fine.  The problem is that this arguably has very little to do with your original sum.

Comment: You have created a transformation from $\mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R^3$ (which is something you can do)

Comment: Remember that $\Bbb R^2$ has no elements in common with $\Bbb R^3$.  There is a very natural *embedding* of $\Bbb R^2$ into $\Bbb R^3$ similar to what you describe, namely looking at $\Bbb R\times\Bbb R\times \{0\}=\{(a,b,0)~:~a,b,\in\Bbb R\}$, but there are other such embeddings possible, e.g. looking instead at $(a,b)\mapsto (0,a,b)$ or even something more exotic such as $(a,b)\mapsto (a,a+b,b)$.  Who is to say that one embedding is "more useful" than another and that this should be the embedding used canonically when trying to add a vector from $\Bbb R^2$ to one from $\Bbb R^3$.

Answer (score 1):

You can embed the 2-dim vector in many different ways.  So in general the question really makes no sense at all.  As several comments indicate, if you state your specific embedding as indicated (and nothing prevents you from doing so) you can do what you've stated.  But I would argue that the operation is completely undefined mathematically.  It is, at the very least, ambiguous.  Baring the embedding trick, I would think that the binary operation "+" is only strictly defined as a map from VXV-->V, and not VXW-->W (or V).

Answer (score 0):

If it is understood that your ordered pairs are $(x,y)$ while your ordered triples are $(x,y,z)$, then it is perfectly fine to identify $(x,y)$ with the  point $(x,y,0)$ and add the two triples together.